# A problem involving centralizers and order of elements.

Tags: group-theory

Let $a$ be an element of a group $G$ such that $|a| = 5$. Show that $C_G(a)=C_G(a^3)$, where $C_G(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$ in $G$.

Also, find an element $a$ of some group $G$ such that $|a|=6$ but $C_G(a)$ is not equal to $C_G(a^3)$.

Comment: Here's a hint. If $a$ is an element of a group and $k \in \mathbb N$, then $C(a) \subseteq C(a^k).$ Please prove that. In your example with $|a| = 5$ this gives $C(a) \subseteq C(a^3)$. Now try to express $a$ as a power of $a^3$, i.e. find a $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $a = (a^3)^k$. Finding this $k$ is strongly related to finite cyclic groups. If we have this $k$, we can conclude $C(a^3) \subseteq C(a)$. Why is this useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to check that $C_G(a)\subseteq C_G(a^3)$. (For example, by saying that $G$ acts on itself by conjugation and $C_G(x)$ is the stabilizer of $x$).

Hence we need to show that $C_G(a^3)\subseteq C_G(a)$. Let $g\in C_G(a^3)$. Then
$$g^{-1}a^3g=a^3$$
Multiply both sides by $g^{-1}a^3g=a^3$:
$$g^{-1}a^3gg^{-1}a^3g=a^6$$
We are done because $a^6=a$.

Comment: and what about the other part where |a|=6 & we need to prove that C(a) is not equal to C(a^3) ?